# ABI incompatibility while importing `scipy.sparse`

Tags: python

I'm running a script in a virtual environment on a new machine. Running the script gives me the following traceback.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zoneMapRGB.py", line 11, in <module>
    from skimage import io, color
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ._io import *
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..color import rgb2grey
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/color/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .colorconv import (convert_colorspace,
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/color/colorconv.py", line 368, in <module>
    rgb_from_xyz = linalg.inv(xyz_from_rgb)
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 947, in inv
    a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py", line 228, in _asarray_validated
    import scipy.sparse
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "/opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: /opt/matlab/extern/engines/python/dist/matlab/engine/glnxa64/../../../../../../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /opt/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

It seems `scipy` is trying to get `libstdc++.so.6` from a `matlab` folder instead of the `python` directory. Is there any way to correct this behavior?

Comment: This looks like a problem with SciPy, not skimage.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thanks for the clarification! I haven't seen this sort of issue before. I tried searching for information on ABI incompatibility and how to resolve it, but I wasn't able to find anything very helpful. If you have any more information or direction to sources, it would help me out

Comment: It looks like your SciPy installation is broken; are you running any of this from inside MATLAB?

Comment: There are calls to the matlab API later in the script, but the code hasn't made it that far. Like I said, I've tried to upgrade scipy, but that hasn't worked

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2/issues/92